# Highest version of glibc working on actual 386 hardware

Tags: linux, compiling, glibc, x86

I need to build a working minimal Linux environment that will run on ACTUAL 386 class hardware. I know that I have to use kernel <3.8, which is not a problem. The issue is with `glibc`, as it seems recent versions (for now I tried `Glibc-2.23`) don't work (or even compile) using only 386 code. I managed to compile for i486, but it does not work on actual hardware. I've tested on a number of different 486 systems and the problem is always the same - the kernel boots, mounts the `root` fs, and then executed `init`, which fails with an error in `sysdeps/i386/cacheinfo.c`, in function `handle_intel` and the error is that the assertion `maxcpuid>=2` fails, at which point the system hangs. The same happens on i586 class machines (Intel Pentium, Pentium MMX). Everything works fine with i686 class hardware (Pentium PRO and up). All packages (including glibc) have been compiled with `-march=i486 -mcpu=i486` flags with `gcc-5.3.0` Using "ready made" old PC distros like dslinux or puppylinux is unfortunately out of the question, as these are very outdated and limited. Any ideas?

Comment: thx for the edit, looks much clearer now

Comment: I have definitely never attempted compiling for an actual 386.  Yet, if I would attempt it I would try to use the configure switch `--host=i386-pc-linux-gnu` instead of trying `-march`/`-mcpu` directly.  This is just a guess though.

Comment: I have actually done both. I have replaced my `uname` with a script that always returned `i486-pc-linux-gnu` as well as modified the CFLAGS to force `-march` and `-mcpu`. As explained trying to compile for `i386-pc-linux-gnu` fails. The kernel itself compiles without trouble with same `gcc-5.3.0` and works on actual hardware up to the point where execution is trasfered to `init`

Comment: I need to argue that I am very surprised that glibc is not backward compatible.  The GNU guys are mad about backward compatibility and support for different flavours of *nix.  Going through all the code of glibc is not manageable, what I would try is to go through [configure.ac](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=configure.ac;h=33bcd621804e9b06d3fa12d09fef84291e7af891;hb=HEAD), there is **a lot** of C code defines in there (although I did not see `maxcpuid` in there).  All in all this may be the right question for savannah-hackers maillist.

Comment: The departure from pure 386 support was announced quite a while ago, but a promise of 486 compatibility was given. Anyway, I have retested to obtain more precise info about the error, and it is in the file 'sysdeps/i386/cacheinfo.c', in function 'handle_intel' and the error is that the assertion 'maxcpuid>=2' fails.

Comment: Is uclibc-ng an option? I know it's not what you're asking, but  at least others viewing the question may find this to be an excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

`cacheinfo.c` was moved into `glibc` between 2007 and 2010, with `glibc-2.23`, excluding the 80386 because it had no cache.

Support for the 386 was withdrawn in late 2012 so you really have to use the `kernel`, `glibc` and `gcc` from mid 2012 at the latest.

2012 is not so late. I still use a 2002 machine. Some things run fine, others don't (html has changed and https is everywhere now).

Think about what you want to do on the machines.

When I was at university we used 486 machines but many of the programs were executed on a vax and the local machines were X clients.